# How to extract only the first items from several span tags using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I only began to learn Beautiful Soup recently. I'm stuck trying to extract only the first items from a part of the html code I recently scraped from a site. I simplified the original html code as below.
The texts I want to extract are in span tag, but the distinguishing part lies in the "i class" tag.

```
src = '''
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 1</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 1</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 1</span>
</div>, 
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 2</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 2</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 2</span>
</div>,
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 3</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 3</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 3</span>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('span')
for d in divs:
    print(d.text)
```

My goal is to extract just the "time 1, time 2, time 3, ...etc."
How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

Select your elements more specific, in your case the parent `div` of the `span` elements and pick only the first one

```
for d in soup.select('div.row.info'):
    print(d.span.text)
```

or directly with [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and `pseudo class`:

```
for s in soup.select('div.row.info span:first-of-type'):
    print(s.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Just use a list comprehension and the step value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works).

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = '''
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 1</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 1</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 1</span>
</div>, 
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 2</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 2</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 2</span>
</div>,
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 3</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 3</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 3</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
first_ones = [s.getText() for s in soup.find_all('span')][::3]
print(first_ones)
```

Output:

```
['time 1', 'time 2', 'time 3']
```

Answer (score -1):

I think one way you could do this is by finding the elements by their class after getting them all:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = '''
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 1</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 1</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 1</span>
</div>, 
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 2</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 2</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 2</span>
</div>,
<div class="row info">
<span><i class="aaa"></i>time 3</span>
<span><i class="bbb"></i>place 3</span>
<span><i class="ccc"></i>spot 3</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all()

for d in divs:
    if 'aaa' in d.get('class', []):
        print(d.parent.text.strip())
```

output:

```
time 1
time 2
time 3
```